# table data displayed when dropdown value changes but not when textbox value changes in C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have 2 textboxes and 1 dropdown with a table where the data gets displayed.
when the dropdown value gets changed multiple times the data is displayed according to it.
But when textbox value is entered for the first time, the data is displayed according to it.
Again when I change the values of the textbox the table gets empty.

```
        IWebElement empName = driver.FindElement(By.Name("employeeName"));
        IWebElement empType = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/select"));
        SelectElement eType = new SelectElement(empType);
        IWebElement city = driver.FindElement(By.Name("city"));
        IWebElement btnSearch = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/a"));

        empType.Click();
        eType.SelectByIndex(2);

        btnSearch.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        empType.Click();
        eType.SelectByValue("1");

        btnSearch.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        empType.Click();
        eType.SelectByText("All");

        btnSearch.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        empName.Click();
        empName.SendKeys("name");

        btnSearch.Click();
        
        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        empName.Clear();
        empType.Click();
        eType.SelectByValue("1");

        btnSearch.Click();
        
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        
        city.Click();
        city.SendKeys("Los Angeles");

        btnSearch.Click();

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        empType.Click();
        eType.SelectByText("All");

        btnSearch.Click();
```

I don't know why the data is not getting displayed according to the textbox values after the first search.
**Kindly someone help me with this. Either with a better way to write this piece of code or by editing this code.**

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: One more thing. Is this the right way to write test case? I'm new to this, So please someone enlight me

Comment: btnSearch.Click(); Are you moving between pages here?

Comment: Only once the data gets displayed when textbox values are entered. when the value changes it does not return the data again @undetectedSelenium

Comment: It happens in the same page @ArundeepChohan

Answer (score -2):

You have to write the By on the upper side and find element on lower side this will does not hamper execution when the actual page loaded in between. also you have to create wrapper method to use explicit wait for performing any action on webelement.

```
    By empName = By.Name("employeeName");
    By empType = By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/select");
    
    By city = By.Name("city");
    By btnSearch = By.XPath("//*[@id='content']/div/form/div[2]/div[4]/a");

    driver.findElement(empType).Click();
    eType.SelectByIndex(2);

    driver.FindElement(btnSearch).Click();
```